# In notepad++, keyboard shortcut should do different things based on current state of notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, I would like the same keyboard shortcut to fold all blocks if not folded AND to unfold all blocks if folded. I know this can be done with 2 shortcuts now. But why not have the same shortcut for folding as well as unfolding depending on current state of folding in the document?

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like the same keyboard shortcut to fold all blocks if not folded AND to unfold all blocks if folded

> why not have the same shortcut for folding as well as unfolding depending on current state of folding in the document?

The developers chose not to provide this functionality.

You could either [make a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) or [download the source code](https://github.com/donho/notepad-plus-plus) and implement it yourself.

Comment: So there is not a plugin or some other way to make this work?

Comment: Not as far as I know.